# How to show two columns in combobox dropdown?

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to show two columns in combobox dropdown. In this image dropdown shows only Company Id, I neet to show company Id and its name in dropdown. How to show it?? Please Help..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Kuh.jpg

Comment: possibly duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091414/winforms-combobox-with-multiple-columns-c

Comment: duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189132/combobox-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

In sql query, you can concatenate the Company id and Name. So you can display both.

Eg: select CompanyID+' '+CompanyName as Company,Id  from yourtable